# Excel formula building

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create an excel formula that will increase a number in a cell by 1 when a specific number is entered in cell a14. In my worksheet I have 10 colours listed, each with a number from 1 to 10. What I am trying to do is be able to type a number from 1 to 10 in cell a14 and for it to then count up by 1 in the cell next to the corresponding colour, which will be cells c3 to c12. We ran a vote at work and I need to be able to log how many votes each colour received. The link below is to a screenshot of my worksheet.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The mentioned link is missing.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please understand, we are not a excel formula building service, they are websites you can pay to have advanced excel documents created we are not that website.  We can help **you** create the document but you must do the work.

Comment: Will you type each vote in a cell (e.g. C14 to C50), or just type all votes in C14 one after each other?

Comment: Hi Máté, my plan was to type a vote in cell a14 one after the other. I have all of the votes in a box and wanted to try and use a formula of this nature to save me having to separate out all the votes into their groups and  counting them manually. Thanks everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF($A$14=A3,C3+1,C3)`
This Formula is a circular reference formula you should change the options in Excel Formulas:
Click on **Enable Iterative Calculation**  and change
the **Maximum Iterations** to 1
and the formula will work drag it down under Vote and whatever you write in A14 the formula will look to the same number under # in Column A and add 1 in the corresponding row (color) in column C.
Check first if Excel has the option of Iterative Calculation.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks very much for this, really appreciated. I will give it a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Sam, this has worked perfectly, thank you so much.